# How to make scala List of Any have a mandatory attribute?

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I'm new to scala and OOP in general, therefore I apologize in advance if the question is stupid, but I really don't know how to find what I'm looking for.

I have the following code

```
case clase MyClass(id: Int, active: Boolean)
case class MyOtherClass(name: String, active: Boolean)


private def myMethod(active: Boolean, list: List[MyClass]): List[MyClass] = {
  if(active){
      list.filter(_.active == true)
  }else{
      list.filter(_.active == false)
  }
}
```

Ok now, what I want to do is to make this "myMethod" take a List of "Any" instead of a specific class as long as it has an "active" attribute. How should I go about it?

For instance, the class:

```
 case class MyThridClass(name: String)
```

wouldn't work since it doesn't have an "active" attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can restructure your code using a trait:

```
trait ActiveTrait {
  val active: Boolean
}


case class MyClass(id: Int, override val active: Boolean) extends ActiveTrait
case class MyOtherClass(name: String, override val active: Boolean) extends ActiveTrait

private def myMethod(active: Boolean, list: List[ActiveTrait]): immutable.Seq[ActiveTrait] = {
  if(active){
    list.filter(_.active)
  } else{
    list.filterNot(_.active)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *structural typing*:

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

case class MyClass(id: Int, active: Boolean)
case class MyOtherClass(name: String, active: Boolean)


def myMethod
  [T <: {def active: Boolean}]
  (active: Boolean, list: List[T])
: List[T] = {
  list.filter(_.active == active)
}

println(myMethod(true, 
  List[{ def active: Boolean }](
    MyClass(42, false), 
    MyOtherClass("foo", true)
  )
))
```

Alternatively, you can leave `Any` in the interface, and do some pattern-matching with reflective calls:

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

case class MyClass(id: Int, active: Boolean)
case class MyOtherClass(name: String, active: Boolean)


def myMethod(active: Boolean, list: List[Any])
: List[Any] = {
  list.filter {
    case a: ({ def active: Boolean }) @unchecked => a.active == active
  }
}

println(myMethod(true, 
  List(
    MyClass(42, false), 
    MyOtherClass("foo", true)
  )
))
```

The first solution is merely slightly inefficient because of method invocations using reflection, but the second variant completely throws any type safety out of the window: if an object does not have `active` method, it will throw a `NoSuchMethodException` at runtime.

Note that there aren't that many cases where you actually need it. Using either proper subclass polymorphism or ad-hoc polymorphism with typeclasses is usually a superior solution, but that would require changes in your api. So, since you've explicitly tagged your question with "design-patterns", I should mention that both `List[Any]` and reflective calls are both rather *anti*patterns.

Comment: Is there anything controversial about the answer itself? It's not like I'm not exposing any sufficiently detailed code so that one cannot pinpoint where exactly the error is...

Comment: It is way too complicated for someone who is new to OOP and Scala. All that is needed is a simple example of using inheritance to provide common functionality for multiple classes.

Comment: @Tim Whether someone is "new to OOP and Scala" or not, is completely irrelevant for the question. This website is about questions / answers, not about the people who ask them. The OP asked specifically *"what I want to do is to make this "myMethod" take a List of "Any" instead of a specific class as long as it has an "active" attribute. How should I go about it?"*. The informal description *"`Any` ... as long as it has an `active` attribute"* translates precisely into the refined type `Any { def active: Boolean }`, so that's what I used in my answer.

Comment: The skill set of the person asking the question is very much part of the question, and should be taken into account when writing an answer.

Comment: @Tim Alright, maybe if one decides to ignore almost the entire question, and instead focus on the *"really don't know how to find what I'm looking for"* and *" How should I go about it?"* parts, one can reinterpret the question as a request to explain the good old subclass polymorphism... Don't give the customer what he asks for, give him what he needs, something like that... Good. (+1) for both solutions with a shared ancestor class / trait.

Comment: I agree that this is more complex than I can handle, but it actually is what I was looking for, I'll look more in depth into structural typing thanks to you, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

In OOP the usual way to do this is to put the common behaviour in a base class and make all your classes inherit from that class.

In Scala it looks like this:

```
abstract class MyBaseClass {
  def active: Boolean
}

case class MyClass(id: Int, active: Boolean) extends MyBaseClass
case class MyOtherClass(name: String, active: Boolean) extends MyBaseClass

def myMethod(active: Boolean, list: List[MyBaseClass]): List[MyBaseClass] =
  list.filter(_.active == active)
```

`extends` is Scala terminology for class inheritance. The base class does not provide a value for `active`, it has to come from a subclass, so the base class is labelled `abstract` to stop the compiler complaining that you can't actually create instances of this class.

If you have an existing set of classes and you can't enforce a common base class with the methods that you need then there are other mechanisms that can be used, such as typeclasses or structural types.

Comment: A trait is probably better than an abstract class here.

Comment: I agree, but I was trying to keep it obvious for someone new to OOP and Scala. I felt that using the word `class` would make the inheritance relationship clearer.

Comment: I'm sorry I took long to answer back. I've tried this before, but the problem here is that when I try to use the method with an object of type "MyClass" it give me an error saying that the types don't match

Comment: @AntonioFerreira Not sure why that is, but hopefully one of the other answers works for you so go with that!

Comment: I just found out why, I was expecting the MyClass and should be expecting the MyBaseClass Instead in the outter function, thank you very much! :)